# Is Finn capable of turning to the dark side?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-finn

Consider that Finn has all the hallmarks of a typical action hero. Compare him to Jason Bourne:

- Both are highly trained and skilled soldiers defecting from an overreaching government with unfathomable resources and sociopathy
- Both are the "top of their class":

  > [*TFA prequel*] At last she said, "FN-2187, your targeting was
  >   exemplary. According to the simulation, you fired your weapon only
  >   thirty-six times, scoring kills with thirty-five of those. You
  >   deployed one explosive, which resulted in the achieving of the
  >   objective and another six enemies killed."
  >
  > [*The Bourne Identity*] I can tell you the license plate numbers of
  >   all six cars outside. I can tell you that our waitress is left-handed
  >   and the guy sitting up at the counter weighs two hundred fifteen
  >   pounds and knows how to handle himself. I know the best place to look
  >   for a gun is the cab or the gray truck outside, and at this altitude,
  >   I can run flat out for a half mile before my hands start shaking. Now
  >   why would I know that? How can I know that and not know who I am?
- Both are forced to engage in combat with their "brethren". Both, despite having a rule against harming innocent people, are willing to kill operatives of their previous allegiance ruthlessly and efficiently

  <sup>It can be argued that the other operatives in Treadstone are not Bourne's "brethren" because they work alone; however, it's obvious from The Bourne Supremacy that they know each other and are capable of empathy/camaraderie to an extent</sup>
- Both are highly valuable assets:

  > [*TFA prequel*] She sighed. She’d had such hope for FN-2187. He had
  >   shown such remarkable promise. He had shown the capacity to be
  >   special.
  >
  > [*The Bourne Identity*] You're U.S. Government property. You're a
  >   malfunctioning $30 million weapon. You're a total goddamn catastrophe,
  >   and by God, if it kills me, you're going to tell me how this happened.
- Both are "haunted" by their job:

  Finn doesn't want to execute innocent people.

  Bourne feels guilty about a job in Berlin.

I could go on but I believe I've made enough examples. Like Finn, Bourne was conditioned to be a killer. Most of Bourne's journey is rejecting this conditioning and going after the source of his training. In the process, Bourne stuggles with his "dark side", aka the blood on his hands. However, speculation [strongly suggests](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111797/is-finn-force-sensitive/111798#111798) that since Rey is the heroine of the film, then it's possible that Rey is more ala Luke and will be tempted to the dark side. Of course, Finn's character alone is a change from the formula and there's nothing to say that the writers won't try to (predictably) alter the formula by having Finn turn to the dark side instead.

So my question is, is there any **evidence** that Finn is capable to turning to the dark side, to make this a plausible potential plot point in a future film?

Comment: Turning to the dark side is only something force sensitives can. As finn seemingly isnt force sensitive so how should he be able to turn to the dark side?

Comment: @Thomas I'm asking for **evidence**. The answer I linked suggested (using evidence) that it's **unknown** if he's force-sensitive.

Comment: Can downvoters explain so I can improve the question or make it clearer?

Comment: Related (duplicate?) question: [is Finn force sensitive?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111797/is-finn-force-sensitive)

Comment: Welcome to the site. :) As Thomas said, turning to the dark side means you're force sensitive so that part has already been asked. If you're asking if he could turn, that's too broad/opinion based. If you're asking will he turn, that's speculative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on the subject, but I think the force can be used easily for good or for evil, making everybody susceptible of turning to the dark side.

Said that, I don't think Finn will turn to the dark side for political reasons.  Making a black character become evil is too risky politicaly speaking, so I think is a safe bet to think Finn will stay in the light until is no longer needed for the sake of the plot, or if the actor asks for too much money for the next movie.

Besides, on the Star Wars franchise there always had only two dark characters. Integrate a third one and make him flip from the Empire to the Rebels and back is too complicated. You have to juggle Rey, Luke, Leia and who know who else in the next movies, it is easier to keep Finn as a pure good one, and let everybody else make things complicated.

Answer (score -2):

## Unlikely

#### Why?: *Because he (most-likely) isn't Force-Sensitive*

As [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111797/is-finn-force-sensitive) asks, and several of the higher answers attempt to prove, Finn isn't force-sensitive, thus, given the general sense of "turning to the Dark Side" meaning a Force-sensitive person using the Dark Side, Finn would not be capable of doing so, since he isn't a Force user at all.

From a certain point of view however, it does raise a secondary interesting question in that, if the Force connects *all* living things, and as we've seen certain locations can have Light / Dark side influence, is it possible for a 'common' person to be influenced by the Dark Side and allow that influence to affect them, or fight it off? If that can shown to be true, then one could make the argument that Finn could, under that understanding, *possibly* be *influenced* and give-in to Dark Side effects, but again, not **use** the Dark Side under the generally accepted definition.

Comment: What reference suggests the Force only affects certain people? The power is known to be ubiquitous. It requires training to control but the question is not limited to control.